# Flavor 'paid' has unknown dimension 'tier'

Tags: android, gradle

I write code from https://developer.android.com/studio/build#flavor_dimensions
but it post error "Flavor 'paid' has unknown dimension 'tier'"

```
flavorDimensions "tier"
productFlavors {
    free {
        dimension "tier"
        applicationId 'com.example.myapp.free'
    }

    paid {
        dimension "tier"
        applicationId 'com.example.myapp.paid'
    }
}
```

Comment: If you only have one dimension, you do not need to specify it in each flavor. Just the first `flavorDimensions "default"` line above is all that's needed.

Comment: I want to know what's the exact reason with "flavor 'paid' has unknow dimension 'tier'"